# Estimating the integral $\int_{0}^\infty x^4 e^{-2x}\,dx$

Tags: sampling, expected-value, gamma-distribution, numerical-integration, accept-reject

We have been given a random variable having a Gamma distribution as shown below:
[image]

Using the accept-reject algorithm, we are supposed to sample from the Gamma distribution using exponential as the proposal distribution. And using this sampler, we are supposed to estimate the following integral:
[image]

I got the samples using accept-reject, but I am unsure how to estimate the integral.

Comment: Your that $X\sim \text{Exp}(2)$, with $E(X)=1/2$, and your integral equals $E(X^4)/2$.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding a bit on the hint in my comment, in your problem $X$ has a $\text{Gamma}(1, 2)$ distribution, thus $E(X)=1/2$. The target integral is

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^4 e^{-2x}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} x^4 2e^{-2x}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}E\left(X^4\right).
$$

Thus having generated values from the distribution of $X$, you can readily approximate $I$ by a sum.

Comment: Why is this in low-quality queue? Sometimes, this doesn't fail to amuse me.

Comment: @User1865345, it could be due to a "trained to exhaustion" NN algorithm that's behind the curtains :-)

Comment: Even Roger's post was in the queue. What bothers me that this didn't happen for the first time.